# Maximum likelihood estimation error | Using optimx package

Tags: r, optimization, statistics, modeling, mle

I am trying to estimate the parameters using maximum likelihood method for income imputation using optimx package in R. I have defined the function, and I am providing the initial parameter vector which has 23 elements. Out of 23, the 21st vector is constrained to have the value of 1.

After few iterations, it says that convergence is reached and when I am trying to find out the parameter value it gives me "NA" for all the parameters. My code is

```
cat("\014")
data = read.csv("DRCOG.csv")
drcog = data    # please make a column in the dataset indicating inc grp. Named as data$grp
param = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)  #initial value of the parameter  


imput = function(param) {              #defining funtion   
  rn = nrow(drcog)
  nc = ncol(drcog)
  inc_thres = matrix(c(-100, 1.5, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.50, 10.0, 13.5, 15.0, 100.0 ),ncol = 12) 
  inc_grp = ncol(inc_thres) - 1
  tinc_thres = t(inc_thres)

  #creating matrix for reportage and group variable
  # equation for reporting income

  reportage = as.matrix(cbind(drcog$uno,drcog$DUGRAD, drcog$AGE5P, drcog$sero, drcog$sero, drcog$sero, drcog$sero, drcog$sero, drcog$sero, drcog$sero))
  nparmr = param[1:10] #number of input variables, change in initial parameter value and equation accordingly

  grp = as.matrix(cbind(drcog$sero, drcog$sero, drcog$sero, drcog$uno, drcog$NVEH, drcog$MALEP, drcog$RENTED, drcog$EMPLP, drcog$SINGUNI, drcog$NWHITE)) 
  nparmg = param[11:21] #number of input variables in grp variable, change in initial parameter value and equation accordingly
  treportage = t(reportage)
  tgrp = t(grp)
  btheq = cbind(treportage, tgrp)
  cncol = ncol(reportage)


  gammar = param[1:10]             #parameter vector of regression
  gammar = as.matrix(gammar)
  gammal = param[11:20]            #parameter vector of group
  gammal = as.matrix(gammal)

  #choleskey matrix as input parameter, variance-covariance matrix in the formula 
  omega_cvar = param[21:23]
  omegaL = matrix(data = 0, nrow = 2, ncol =2)
  omegaL[1, 1] = omega_cvar[1]
  omegaL[2, 1] = omega_cvar[2]
  omegaL[2, 2] = omega_cvar[3]
  omega = omegaL%*%t(omegaL)

  x <- matrix(data=0,nrow =rn,ncol=14) #first col is reporting/missing, 2-12 is probability for each individual and each group 
  library(pbivnorm)        
  x[, 1] = matrix(drcog$grp)

  # threshold matrix calculation 

  th <- matrix(data=0,nrow =rn,ncol=2) 
  for (i in 1:rn){
    curr_cat = x[i, 1]
    if (curr_cat>0) {
      th[i, 1] = inc_thres[1, curr_cat] 
      th[i, 2] = inc_thres[1, curr_cat+1]
    }
  }

  y11 =  reportage%*%gammar  
  y22 =  (grp%*%gammal)
  cor1 = -1* cov2cor(omega)
  LL = matrix(data = 0, nrow = rn, ncol = 1)

  upper_lim = 1e-5
  for (i in 1:rn) {
    curr_cat = x[i, 1]
    if (curr_cat>0) {
      th_low = (th[i, 1] - y22[i, ])/omega[2,2]
      th_up = (th[i, 2] - y22[i, ])/omega[2,2]

      nnn = (pbivnorm(th_up, y11[i, 1], rho = cor1[1, 2]) - pbivnorm(th_low, y11[i, 1], rho = cor1[1, 2]))
      if (nnn > upper_lim) {
        LL[i, 1] = log(nnn)
      }
      else {
        LL[i, 1] = log(upper_lim)
      }

    }
    else {
      nnn = (1 - pnorm(y11[i, 1]))
      if (nnn > upper_lim){
        LL[i, 1] = log(nnn)
      }
      else {
        LL[i, 1] = log(upper_lim)
      }
    }
  }
  return(sum(LL))
}

grad.norm <- function(imput) {
  require(numDeriv)
  return(sum(grad(imput, param)^2))
}


#mle estimation
#install package stats4
library(stats4)
set.seed(123)


#fit1 = optim(par = param, fn = imput, gr = NULL, lower = c(-Inf, -Inf, -Inf, -Inf, -Inf, -Inf, -Inf, -Inf, -Inf, -Inf, -Inf, -Inf, -Inf, -Inf, -Inf, -Inf, -Inf, -Inf, -Inf, -Inf, 1, -Inf, -Inf), upper = c(Inf, Inf, Inf, Inf, Inf, Inf, Inf, Inf, Inf, Inf, Inf, Inf, Inf, Inf, Inf, Inf, Inf, Inf, Inf, Inf, 1.01, Inf, Inf), method = "L-BFGS-B", control = list(trace = 1, REPORT =1))

library(optimx)
fit1 = optimx(param, imput, gr = NULL, lower = c(-Inf, -Inf, -Inf, -Inf, -Inf, -Inf, -Inf, -Inf, -Inf, -Inf, -Inf, -Inf, -Inf, -Inf, -Inf, -Inf, -Inf, -Inf, -Inf, -Inf, 1, -Inf, -Inf), upper = c(Inf, Inf, Inf, Inf, Inf, Inf, Inf, Inf, Inf, Inf, Inf, Inf, Inf, Inf, Inf, Inf, Inf, Inf, Inf, Inf, 1.01, Inf, Inf), method = "L-BFGS-B", control = list(trace = 1, REPORT =1))
```

The output what I am getting is

```
Analytic gradient not made available.
Analytic Hessian not made available.
Scale check -- log parameter ratio= 0   log bounds ratio= 0 
Method:  L-BFGS-B 
iter    1 value -63967.987853
iter    2 value -66454.130893
iter    3 value -66870.500976
iter    4 value -68290.490185
iter    5 value -71406.527209
iter    6 value -71569.074462
Error in if (nnn > upper_lim) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
optim function evaluation failure
Post processing for method  L-BFGS-B 
Save results from method  L-BFGS-B 
$fevals
[1] NA

$convcode
[1] 9999

$value
[1] 8.988466e+307

$par
[1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

I have tried with other optimization packages such as maxLik, maxBFGS, optim. For some reason, there is no convergence there too. Let me know if you need the dataset for the compilation.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how this hasn't been answered in 8 months.  You obviously have an error in your objective function that's giving "if (nnn > upper_lim) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed".  Have you fixed it?